# d3.js Strange dragging behaviour when using dynamic scaling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to build a d3 graph (currently only unconnected nodes) to handle relatively small node values. For this reason I am using a linear scale that reacts dynamically on the input values and scales them accordingly:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
[...]
xScale.domain(d3.extent(layout, function (d){ return d.x; }));
yScale.domain(d3.extent(layout, function (d){ return d.y; }));
```

In the current version (you can find it here: https://jsfiddle.net/mn1wmbe3/6/) the dragging and value changing of single nodes works perfectly fine. This is the code I am using to move a node:

```
node.filter(function(d) { return d.selected; })
    .each(function(d) {
        d.x = xScale.invert(d3.event.x);
        d.y = yScale.invert(d3.event.y);
    })
    .attr("cx", xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", yScale(d.y));
```

As seen in other examples, to be able to move several nodes simultaneously I would need to add the relative coordinates of the drag movement (`d3.event.dx`) to each selected node value. Like this:

```
node.filter(function(d) { return d.selected; })
    .each(function(d) {
        d.x += xScale.invert(d3.event.dx);
        d.y += yScale.invert(d3.event.dy);
    })
    .attr("cx", xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", yScale(d.y));
```

However, this behaves not as expected and moves the nodes way to far. You can see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4evhkzp0/1/).

Do you have any suggestions why that is? Is there a possibility to work around that and move several nodes in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

You should only need a few minor changes to make things work properly. First, change your drag event from:

```
d.x += xScale.invert(d3.event.dx);
d.y += yScale.invert(d3.event.dy);
```

To:

```
d.x = xScale.invert(d3.event.x);
d.y = yScale.invert(d3.event.y);
```

And things will no longer jump around like before. However, if you increase the size of the radius you will notice that when you first start dragging, the object will jump to center around the mouse position. This is because you now need to specify an origin function. Change this code:

```
d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d) {
```

To this:

```
.call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d){return {x:xScale(d.x), y:yScale(d.y)};})
    .on("drag", function(d) {
```

With this, when you drag something it will remember the offset. And now things will behave nicely.

Now to move many nodes relatively you can write your own `dx,dy` function. Simply log the coordinates of the object on `dragstart` and then calculate `dx,dy` on `drag`, and add these values to the other nodes to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically, the error was using dynamic scaling:

```
xScale.domain(d3.extent(layout, function (d){ return d.x; }));
yScale.domain(d3.extent(layout, function (d){ return d.y; }));
```

Because of my test data, this lead to the domain beeing:

```
xScale.domain(-2, 1);
yScale.domain(-1, 0);
```

Which behaves perfectly fine, if you moove your nodes this way:

```
d.x = xScale.invert(d3.event.x);
d.y = yScale.invert(d3.event.y);
```

However, when trying to move nodes by adding the delta distances (`d3.event.dx`) to them, the invertion of the scale lead to unexpected results. The reason for this is the fact that `xScale.invert(1)` returned `-1.994`, which when added to the original value, gave unexpected results.

**Solution**

The workaround I used calculates the distance between the min and max value of the data and sets the domain from zero to this value:

```
 extentX = Math.abs(d3.max(graph.layout, function(d) { return d.x;}) - d3.min(graph.layout, function(d) { return d.x;}));
 extentY = Math.abs(d3.max(graph.layout, function(d) { return d.y;}) - d3.min(graph.layout, function(d) { return d.y;}));
 xScale.domain([0, extentX]);
 yScale.domain([0, extentY]);
```